# Flexbox - make elements shrink to fit on 2 rows and 2 columns with 4 items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I hope I'm doing a good job of describing my question - I have a web application that embeds iframes into a Flexbox div element (whose parent is, for what it's worth, also a flexbox).

The behavior I'm aiming for depends on the number of elements in the Flexbox:

1 item: 100% width, 100% height

2 items: 100% width, 50% height (each)

3 items: 100% width on one iframe, 50% width on the others. 50% height on all iframes

4 items: 50% width, 50% height for all iframes (or a 2x2 grid)

My first instinct was that the flex elements need to have a `grow` of 2, a `shrink` of 0, and a `basis` of 50% to make this work (would grow up to 100%, but no smaller than 50%), as well as a `flex-flow: column wrap` on the Flexbox, but the iframes just stack on top of each other and keep shrinking. The inspect panel shows that the style is being applied properly, so I'm properly stuck.

Can anyone suggest if this is possible or not? I could do this through Javascript but I'd like to try to learn a bit more about Flexbox in the process. Thank you!

Edit: Here's a CodePen with an example of what I'm trying to do: http://codepen.io/jzisser9/pen/beNgOj

Comment: post the code you've tried.. a live demo (e.g. jsfiddle.net) may also be helpful

Comment: I've added a Codepen to the description that shows what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Honestly, your question is not very clear to me. But here's what I put together based on my understanding: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrPpjV?editors=1100

Comment: That's almost it. The only thing is that I'd like the blue squares - the iframes - to fill up any remaining space in the 'main-player' div. If I remove an iframe, the other iframes stay the same size.

Comment: Here's the dilemma: If you want a 2x2 grid, then each flex item must be 50% wide *and not stretch*. If they are allowed to stretch, they will each take the full width of the line, vertically stacking all four items in a single column.

Comment: You could wrap the iframes by row: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyaWeX?editors=1100

Comment: Ok, I think I've had my moment of clarity. I don't know why this didn't occur    to me before, it feels like it should be Flexbox 101. http://codepen.io/jzisser9/pen/zBxZjZ If that works for divs, it ought to work for iframes too.

Comment: With divs its easy. I thought you wanted iframes. There's a difference: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXPpaY?editors=1100